# jasper report custom properties are not accessible in customexporter

Tags: jasper-reports

I am writing my own custom xml exporter for jasper reports. I would like to define some properties in my .jrxml file, which i would like to access them later in my custom xml exporter.

I have added two custom properties(last two). I can see the other two properties in my custom xml exporter but not my custom properties. Is there anything i am missing?

```
<detail>
<band height="13">
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
<reportElement key="auctionCode" x="256" y="0" width="48" height="13" uuid="03408ccf-c8ba-4e4f-8da6-694f02b70e4b">
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.column.name" value="ShipCountry"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.repeat.value" value="true"/>
<property name="com.xxxx.cdt.export.xml.test.value" value="abcdefghij"/>
<property name="com.xxxx.cdt.xml.test1.value1" value="ijklmnopqr"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set a global property to instruct JR to transfer your properties from the JRXML to the generated report.

Include something like the following in your jasperreports.properties:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.print.transfer.xxxx=com.xxxx.cdt
```

Comment: Yeah. I tried that way. Anyway thanks for your reply.